# Webview with Pinch zoom not working when the content more than height and having scroll?

Tags: android, webview, pinchzoom

I am using webview in my application.
The Same webview is supporting pinch zoom for some websites and not supporting for some websites.
Usually I have set all the webview settings also like

```
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

But when loading the some websites  having vertically scrolled content are unable to work for pincn zoom.
other websites like having horizontal scrolling and fixed content are able to work for pinch zooming.

Please suggest me if any one solve this kind of behaviour with webview.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some mobile pages are designed to fit the device width, with some attribute `width=device-width` or even `user-scalable=no` in the **meta** filed of the page. In this case zooming is disabed by browser.

Comment: how to enable it from mobile, as in my application I am uploading any random file,it can be pdf or doc etc?